# Groovy - Multi Table Spin to File

Tags: java, sql, groovy, groovy-console

I am running a multi table SQL call that kicks out to a file.write.  The code works in SQuirreL and even in Groovy until I get to the file.write("") lines (the last4 lines of the code). The first error message I get it "because: ORA-00911: invalid character", the rest are similar to it.

This is where I think the error is located:

```
file.write("")
db.eachRow(sql) {
    file.append(it.MOPID + "\t" + it.EOM + "\t" + it.Mopstart + "\n")
```

I think the issue with my code is that there is more than one table and at the time of write something is getting all jacked up.  Your knowledge is greatly appreciated.

Respectfully ~ Corpa Loom <3

Below is the code in full:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def db = Sql.newInstance(
    'jdbc:oracle:thin:@XX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX:ORCL',
    'reporter', 'XXXXXXX', 'oracle.jdbc.XXXX.OracleDataSource')

def sql = """
DROP TABLE TEMPXMOP24;

CREATE TABLE TEMPXMOP24
(
   MOPID VARCHAR2(12),
   TYPE VARCHAR2(200),
   MOPSTART DATE,
   MOPAPPROVEDTIME DATE,
   TIME_DIF VARCHAR2(45),
   TIME_ORDER NUMBER(10),
   FIXED_MOP VARCHAR2(12),
   MOP_HR VARCHAR2(2)
);

INSERT INTO TEMPXMOP24 (MOPID,TYPE,MOPSTART,MOPAPPROVEDTIME,TIME_DIF,TIME_ORDER,FIXED_MOP,MOP_HR)
SELECT MOPACTIVITY.MOPID,
MOPACTIVITY.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED "TYPE",
MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART,
MOPACTIVITY.MOPAPPROVEDTIME,
ROUND(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART -  MOPACTIVITY.MOPAPPROVEDTIME,2)||' days' "TIME_DIF",
ROUND(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART -  MOPACTIVITY.MOPAPPROVEDTIME,0) "TIME_ORDER",
 (CASE 
  WHEN SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 7, 2) = '24' THEN SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 1, 6)||'00'||SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 9, 4)
  ELSE MOPACTIVITY.MOPID
 END ) FIXED_MOP,
(CASE 
  WHEN SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 7, 2) = '24' THEN SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 7, 2)
  ELSE SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 7, 2)
 END ) MOP_HR 
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY
WHERE MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART -  MOPACTIVITY.MOPAPPROVEDTIME BETWEEN 0 and 14;

SELECT * FROM TEMPXMOP24
WHERE TRUNC(TO_DATE(FIXED_MOP, 'MMDDYYHH24MISS'))
  BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-90) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
ORDER BY "TIME_ORDER"
"""

def date = new Date() 
def dts = date.format("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") 
File file = new File('C:/OUTPUT/' +dts  + ' Past Due CM Mops.xls')

file.write("")
db.eachRow(sql) {
    file.append(it.MOPID + "\t" + it.TYPE + "\t" + it.MOPSTART + "\n")
}
```

Comment: If instead of writing it to file, you did a println- does it work?

Comment: Ok, just looked up the error message - and it says that there's a special character in the sql statement.  The first thing I'd do would is to try db.eachRow(sql.toString())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your fix Copra.  Really good to see you this past weekend.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def db = Sql.newInstance(
    'jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.47.193:1521:ORCL',
    'reporter', 'r3p0rt3r', 'oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource')

def sql = """
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT MOPACTIVITY.MOPID,
MOPACTIVITY.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED "TYPE",
MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART,
MOPACTIVITY.MOPAPPROVEDTIME,
ROUND(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART -  MOPACTIVITY.MOPAPPROVEDTIME,2)||' days' "TIME_DIF",
ROUND(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART -  MOPACTIVITY.MOPAPPROVEDTIME,0) "TIME_ORDER",
 (CASE 
  WHEN SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 7, 2) = '24' THEN SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 1, 6)||'00'||SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 9, 4)
  ELSE MOPACTIVITY.MOPID
 END ) FIXED_MOP,
(CASE 
  WHEN SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 7, 2) = '24' THEN SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 7, 2)
  ELSE SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 7, 2)
 END ) MOP_HR 
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY
WHERE MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART -  MOPACTIVITY.MOPAPPROVEDTIME BETWEEN 0 and 14)
WHERE TRUNC(TO_DATE(FIXED_MOP, 'MMDDYYHH24MISS'))
  BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-90) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
ORDER BY "TIME_ORDER"
    """
def date = new Date() 
def dts = date.format("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") 
File file = new File('C:/Output/' + dts + ' EXPEDITE_MOPS.xls')
file.write("")
db.eachRow(sql) {
    file.append(it.MOPID + "\t" + it.TYPE + "\n")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you check the sql returning any rows in the first place. I fiddled your SQL and it turns out to be an invalid one. The way you have your sql written right now will not return any row at all although it says it is valid.

**Expected Problem:**
`AND to_char(mopactivity.mopend, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:') > '2013-05-28 06:01'`

In the above line you are trying to compare two `varchars` of different formats which would never yield any result.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0992/5) tailored for your sql with the correct formats. Try that out.

Comment: My sql seems to run without a hitch and I can even export it to Excel from SQuirreL.  I can't help but wonder in a multi table SQL call and then wanting to write to file, how do you make sure that you have the table that you want to export Selected or Focused before you start the file.write?